# No sign of a dual boot after installation

Tags: dual-boot

I tried to install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 7..everything went well, and it said that I had to restart the system. I restarted & took out the USB, but it booted directly to Windows 7. I tried the installation again, but apparently Ubuntu was properly installed in the first time itself... re installing doesn't work. I had left about 78 GB worth of free space on my hard drive. When I checked the control panel for the disk partitions, it had two separate allocations for the 78 GB..one as 70 GB and the other as 8 GB. Neither of the two partitions were shown as free space, but rather as Healthy Primary Partitions.

What do I do?

Comment: first, while booting windows press constantly `F8` to enter the windows repair/boot menu and see if there is Ubuntu listed. Do you know where did you install the bootloader? If not try installing Ubuntu again and see what it chooses by default (you can see that in other solution option, there is a listbox with boot loader location choice). After that you can cancel instalation.

Comment: @Misery Ubuntu **never** appears in the Windows boot menu unless installed via Wubi, which isn't the case here.